# How can I create a zipped file in Python that when unzipped will give me the raw files rather than a folder?

Tags: python, zip, os.walk, os.path

For an assignment for my internship, I was asked to create a script that moved files around in folders and eventually zipped the contents of a final folder. The desired finish project is a zipped file that when opened will place all 1,348 files into the folder that the .zip file is uncompressed in. Currently, I am running into the problem in which when I unzip my finished file, it reveals the folder in which all the files were originally apart of.

Here is a screenshot of what is produced when I unzip test.zip. As you can see, the "compressed" folder is placed into the folder when I ideally want the contents of "compressed" folder to be there.

*NOTICE* 
Well apparently I can't upload an image until I have a higher "reputation". So, imagine a folder with two files in it: test.zip and a folder named "compressed"

Here is my code, thanks for any help!

```
zf = zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip","w")
for dirname, subdirs, files in os.walk('./compressed'):
for filename in files:
    zf.write(os.path.join(dirname,filename))
zf.close
```

Comment: I don't really see where these two can be compared.

Comment: Where do you see that these two can not be compared?

Comment: Nevermind, I see it now. Thank you for the redirection.